# How do I export a single instance of a class and import that same instance in multiple files?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, import, module

I have a base file that contains a class:

File-1:

```
class Foo {
   constructor() {
     this.count = 0;
   }
}

export = new Foo();
```

Then I import this instance in two other files:

File-2:

```
import Foo = require("./File-1");
Foo.count = 6;
export const logFile2Count = () => console.log(Foo.count); // 6
```

File-3:

```
import Foo = require("./File-1");
export const logFile3Count = () => console.log(Foo.count); // 0
```

File-4:

```
import { logFile2Count } from "./File-2";
import { logFile3Count } from "./File-3";

logFile2Count(); // "6"
logFile3Count(); // "0" (Expected 6)
```

I want the state of Foo to stay persistent throughout all files that it's imported in. I.e. I want to import a reference of Foo in each file as oppose to a copy of Foo in each file. How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to the community Dylan. I think simply, applying `Singleton Pattern` for the class `Foo` will solve your issue.

Comment: Hi denizkanmaz thanks but I was able to solve the issue using more conventional import/export patterns. I have had a look at the Singleton Pattern and it doesn't seem like a very clean solution to me. Others might disagree though so I think it's worth posting an answer for it so people can see.

Comment: What is this `import Foo = require("./File-1");`?  That's not a valid syntax.  You either use `import` or `require()`, not both.  You are either using CommonJS modules or ESM modules and their matching syntax.  Don't mix in the same import.  And in this case, there may be a difference which you are using because `import` gets static imports, not generated imports like your singleton.

Comment: This is in tsc and babel. To do default `export =` then you have to do the require to make tsc compiler happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure but after some experimentation this is because of the way `require` behaves in relation to the import statement (probably something to do with the way tsc/babel is transpiling the code); It runs the entire code in the file and then gives you the exported values. If you change to use an `import` statement then it will work because it gives you a reference to the class when exporting as oppose to running the whole file and giving you a new instance.

This will give you the behaviour you intend:

File-1:

```
class Foo {
   constructor() {
     this.count = 0;
   }
}

const foo = new Foo();
export foo;
```

File-2:

```
import { foo } from "./File-1";
/** -- snip -- **/
```

Comment: This is legal ESM module syntax.  ESM has static exports, it doesn't run the code first so you can't have computed exports like you can with CommonJS modules.  It's a design change they made when designing EMS exports, perhaps largely as a favor to bundlers whose job is a lot easier with static exports.  It happens to make compatibility between the two types of modules within node.js a major pain in the toosh if you are already using computed exports in a CommonJS module.

Comment: Where can I read more about this? When I tried to google this issue I found nothing. Is there a post somewhere explaining this more in detail?

Comment: I don't know of a good resource.  I spent days trying to understand how to make an existing CommonJS module (with computed exports) be compatible with ESM import and reading everything I could find and eventually pieced enough together to understand basically what was going on, only to conclude that nodejs compatibility between the two is a work-in-progress.  You simply cannot load some CommonJS modules into an ESM module without all sorts of hacks.  In what you show, it seems like you should just stick entirely to ESM syntax and not use any computed exports.

Comment: Here are a couple references: [Differences between CommonJS modules and ESM modules](https://dev.to/exacs/node-js-12-supports-es-modules-do-you-know-the-difference-between-commonjs-and-es2015-modules-hg9) and [Nodejs documentation on modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_differences_between_es_modules_and_commonjs) and [Discussion of future changes in node.js related to module interoperability](https://github.com/nodejs/modules/issues/448).

Comment: Also horribly, you can't import a module by just importing its directory like you can with CommonJS/require.  So, whoever is importing has to manually know the main file for the import, nodejs won't automatically retrieve that info from package.json like it would with CommonJS modules.  This is not big deal for modules within your project which you already import by direct file reference, but is a pain for external and shared modules.  I hope they fix this too.  ESM modules in node.js seem like version 0.5., not 1.0.  Maybe the TypeScript compiler hides some of the mess.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the links. So basically just NEVER combine import and require since compatibility between the two is still unstable due to the fact that they are fundamentally designed differently - It doesn't really help that there are SO posts with thousands of upvotes recommending that you combine the two to make tsc compiler happy when trying to do a default export with ESM modules.

Comment: It's not "unstable" (in the sense that there are lots of bugs).  It just lacks full feature compatibility and may never get that.  ESM export requires statically named exports without running the code.  CommonJS does not do statically named exports at all other than one default object.  All the other CommonJS exports are dynamic (properties you assign to `module.exports`.  If you can live entirely within ESM syntax and can live without computed exports, then you're OK.  But, trying to load a CommonJS module that has computed exports from within an ESM module is a pain.

Comment: Perhaps relevant: [ESM modules - exporting single instance design pattern](https://k94n.com/es6-modules-single-instance-pattern)

Answer (score 1):

Actually I tried the below in node js using require instead import. It seems to work as expected
File-1.js

```
class Foo {
   constructor() {
     this.count = 0;
   }
}

module.exports = new Foo();
```

File-2.js

```
let Foo = require("./File-1");
Foo.count = 6;
module.exports.logFile2Count = () => console.log(Foo.count); // 6
```

File-3.js

```
let Foo = require("./File-1")
module.exports.logFile3Count = () => console.log(Foo.count); // 0
```

File-4.js

```
let  {logFile2Count} = require("./File-2");
let  {logFile3Count} = require("./File-3");

logFile2Count(); // "6"
logFile3Count(); // "0" (Expected 6)
```

This is the output I got

```
node File-4.js 
6
6
```

Comment: This is not the code that I posted though... It''s because of how the require statement is working.

Answer (score 0):

well, if there isn't any form of sync. between `File-2.js` and `File-3.js` modules, before reading from `File-1.js` (like `File-2.js` depends on `File-3.js` or viceversa) i think you can only set the value directly in the common dependency `File-1.js` to be 100% sure that the dependant modules read the same values.

This because the code becomes a kind of [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition)